# Error getbyclassname VBA Web Scraping from search engine

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I keep getting error "object doesn't support this property or method " when using getelementsbyClassName. I want to get all urls of the web pages that are resulted from the search engine Baidu (Baidu.com). But I could not "click" next page of the search engine. I have tried for days, it would be good if someone could help me. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GettingURL()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim c As Long, u As Long
    c = 3
    Dim e
    Dim PageCount As Long

    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.baidu.com"

        'searching for the word on the search enigne
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")("wd").Value  = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2).Value
        .document.getElementById("su").Click

        'getting result for page 1 to 20
        For PageCount = 1 To 20

            'loop until the end to get resulting url and navigate to it
            Do
            Loop Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            .navigate .document.URL

            'navigating page and this line causes problem:
            .document.GetelementByClassName("pc")(0) = PageCount

            'getting the url of all the search result in the result page
            While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            With .document.querySelectorAll("#content_left h3 [href]")
                For u = 0 To 50
                    Sheets("Data").Cells(c, 1) = .Item(u)
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End With

            PageCount = PageCount + 1
        Next

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your error message is a missing `"s"` in the method:

```
GetelementByClassName
```

That should be `getElementsByClassName` as it returns a collection.

---

You can click the next button with

```
ie.document.querySelector("a.n").Click
```

`a.n` is a CSS selector combination for an `a` tag element with class name `n`. The first match is returned by `querySelector` method.

You can see the target element here:

[image]

And the CSS selector in action here:

[image]

---

You can loop through all the pages with the following method:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GettingURL()
    Dim i As Long
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://baidu.com/s?wd=Red"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend

        Dim aNodeList As Object: Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".pc")

        For i = 1 To aNodeList.Length - 1
           aNodeList.item(i).Click
           While .Busy Or .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend
           Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".pc")
        Next
        Stop '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you understand the above?

Comment: thanks for replying! However, after getting to the next page, the .navigate does not seem to follow the new url. so I can't go to the third page or get the information from second page.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would love to accept your answer. However, I still met a problem, how to navigate to the new URL after each page change? I need to navigate to the new URL so that .document.querySelectorAll("#content_left h3 [href]") can be used to abstract information from the new page

Comment: Also, in the above, you don't need to navigate. The page is already updated. The .document gets refreshed each time. In each new page (after each click) I am setting  Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".pc") again because of this as the document has changed. Have you watched the code running? You will see the page  numbering at the bottom changing.